# С# выяснить содержимое листа при GetType().GetFields

Tags: c#

Мы узнаем количество полей и их значение в классе следующим образом

```
     object bobik = new dog();
     foreach(FieldInfo field in bobik.GetType().GetFields())
     {
      Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", field.FieldType, field.Name, 
      field.GetValue(bobik));
     }
```

Но если нам в классе, встретится например, list, то консоль нам выведет

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ClassName] fieldName
```

Как в процессе развернуть лист тоже? Можно сделать

```
if(field.GetType().IsArray)
{
SomeAction
}
```

Но нельзя сделать

```
IsList
```

Как можно в итоге вытащить и развернуть этот лист тоже?

Comment: Можно, разворачивать Generic. field.FieldType.IsGeneric и т д.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У `FieldInfo` есть свойство `FieldType` - это тип, который вам нужен. Для примера можно сделать так:

```
Type type = field.FieldType;
if(type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>))
{
    Type itemType = type.GetGenericArguments()[0]; // use this...
}
```

Ссылки на источники:

- [C# generic list  how to get the type of T](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1043778/5275890)
- [How to get the type of T from a member of a generic class or method?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/557349/5275890)
- [Свойство `FieldInfo.FieldType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo.fieldtype(v=vs.110).aspx)

Метод `GetGenericArguments` возвращает массив объектов. Поэтому можно убрать `[0]` и работать с массивом (к примеру через `foreach`).

Comment: Но ведь приведённый вами код покажет только первый объект в листе. Можно как то пролистать его полностью, без указаний на [0]?

Comment: @Dmitrii Метод `GetGenericArguments` возвращает массив объектов. Поэтому можно убрать [0] и работать с массивом (к примеру через `foreach`). Понятно пояснил?